# Change Date Once A Week

Tags: javascript

Is there a way with Javascript to update a date once a week?

For example: I have a weekly menu that changes every Tuesday. So today the title would be "Menu For June 18th, 2013" but as soon as next Tuesday arrives on the 25th, I want the menu to update to say "Menu For June 25th, 2013" automatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, just think about it logically. You're looking for the most recent Tuesday. So basically it's a loop where you start with today, and go backwards until you hit a Tuesday, then stop - that's your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var monthname=new Array('January','February','March','April',
                        'May','June','July','August','September',
                        'October','November','December');

var day = new Date();

while (day.getDay() != 2) day = new Date(day.valueOf()-86400000);

var suffix;
switch (day.getDate() % 10) {
    case 1 : suffix = 'st';
    case 2 : suffix = 'nd';
    case 3 : suffix = 'rd';
    default : suffix = 'th';
}

alert('Menu for ' + day.getDate() + suffix + ' ' 
      + monthname[day.getMonth()] +  ' ' + day.getFullYear());
```

Note that JS has the *rather* annoying January = 0, February = 1.... feature.

Apologies - I will have sent you to infinte loop-land with my last post - So this is corrected and also has formatting as you outline in your question.

Comment: Having edited this post about 20 times I have come to the conclusion that JS really does need `.addDays()`!!! arrrrgh. I'm sure there's a library though...

Comment: What is the 86400000 all about? is that how many milliseconds are in a day?

Comment: that was more of a rhetorical comment for other people reading your answer

Comment: @zer0ruth Sorry, I was only pulling your leg!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `getDay()` method on the `Date` object, which returns the day of the week as an integer (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ... 6 = Saturday)

```
function mostRecentTuesday()
{
    var date = new Date();

    // 2 == tuesday
    while(date.getDay() != 2)
    {
        // rewind a day
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    }

    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it without looping.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (86400000 * (2 - (d.getDay() > 1 ? 
                                   d.getDay() : d.getDay() + 7))));
```

`d` will always be the past Tueday or today.

Comment: +1 I was considering going down the no loop route but for the sake of a max of 6 iterations I doubt it will be a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score -4):

you can check in javascript if the day today is tuesday and then when it is, just update the value of something to the current date, check out the date functions within javascript

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

but you'll use

```
var tuesday = new Date().getDay();

if (tuesday === 2){
  // do somehting
}
```

don-t pin me down on the number two, not 100% sure if that would be tuesday but the var tuesday will return a int from 0-6, not sure if it starts sunday or monday

Comment: really, cause that's just your opinion, for understanding prinicples it's perfectly fine, and don't just knock a site without explaining why

Comment: if tuesday === 2 still requires a hardcoded date though doesn't it?

Comment: @zer0ruth No you can output todays date by outputting `new Date()` in various formats

Comment: Regardless, isn't this incomplete because if the day was not tuesday, how would it know to write the last one? Unless it was written to a database or file it wouldn't be able to get it. This would only be able to change the date on the day it needed to be changed. For all other days there is no logic here to provide the previous date.

Comment: -1 for a couple of reasons (not too fussed regarding w3schools...) - a) setting a var `tuesday` to the current date is a poor choice of variable name as it will only make sense 1/7th of the time. b) this code doesn't do what the OP asks. They want to know when the last Tuesday was - not whether today is a Tuesday or not.

Comment: @TobiasHagenbeek For the record, a link to w3fools is plenty of explanation.